# template_redirect and title

Tags: hooks, title, include, template-redirect, wp-title

I pass a template_redirect in wordpress as hook but I want to have a personnalized title for this page and I miss to do that.
Has someone any idea ?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'virtual_pages' );
function virtual_pages() {
    global $wp;
    if (strtolower($wp->request) == 'virtual-page'){ 
        remove_all_actions( 'builder_add_title' );
        add_action( 'builder_add_title', "<title>Custom Title</title>\n" );
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/test.php' );
       exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework or what? `builder_add_title` does not seem to be WordPress thing.

Comment: @Nilambar: I don't use any framework. Only wordpress but it doesn't work, so It's probably for that. Any idea on how to do ?